# load mongoose model from other controller in yeoman angular-fullstack project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am writing an application using yeoman angular-fullstack,
I defined some entities that I would like to access from other entities controller.
For example I have in my server->api->Mall I have the following code:

```
var MallSchema = new Schema({
  ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mall', MallSchema);
```

in other Business controller I would like to search for Mall by _id, using mongoose, But I can not import MallSchema trying to do the following:

```
mall = mongoose.models("MallSchema").find({_id: "some_mall_id"})
business.mallType = mall.type
business.update();
```

or nesting Schema's

```
var MallSchema = new Schema({
  business : Business;
});
```

I really tried in lot of ways, ending up with frustration, googling this yields lots of answers, none have works and few just seems too complicated like [this one](http://www.white-skies.com/2013/02/how-to-set-up-mongoose-mongo-schemas.html), I newbie to node.js so I mast been missing somthing simple. any help would be nice for the entire community.

Answer (score 0):

it seems simple but somehow missed from documentation
this seems to work for me now

```
var business = require('../business/business.model')();
var user = require('../user/user.model')()
```

Hope it helps.